# akka http to use Json Support and xmlsupport

Tags: scala, akka-http

I want to print data in xml format when department is "hr"but data in json format when department is "tech" .

**Can we use 
spray-json Support https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/common/json-support.html and XML support  https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/common/xml-support.html together**

```
 private[rest] def route =
  (pathPrefix("employee") & get) {
    path(Segment) { id =>
      parameters('department ? "") { (flag) =>
        extractUri { uri =>
          complete {
            flag match {
              case "hr": =>  {

            HttpEntity(MediaTypes.`application/xml`.withCharset(HttpCharsets.`UTF-8`),"hr department")
            }
              case "tech" =>{
                HttpEntity(ContentType(MediaTypes.`application/json`), mapper.writeValueAsString("tech department"))

              }

            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Solution I tried
I tried the below by using by using JsonProtocols and ScalaXmlSupport I get the compile error expected ToResponseMarshallable but found Department

```
case class department(name:String)
private[rest] def route =
  (pathPrefix("employee") & get) {
    path(Segment) { id =>
      parameters('department ? "") { (flag) =>
        extractUri { uri =>
          complete {
            flag match {
              case "hr": =>  {

            complete(department(name =flag))
            }
              case "tech" =>{
                complete(department(name =flag))

              }

            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes you can ! Please describe the problem you're encountering :-)

Comment: I am not able to find a proper example for xml support

Comment: @C4stor updated code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are several issues you have to overcome to achieve what you want:

1. You want to customize response type basing on the request parameters. It means standard `implicit`-based marshaling will not work for you, you'll have to do some explicit steps
2. You want to marshal into an XML-string some business objects. Unfortunately, [`ScalaXmlSupport`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/common/xml-support.html) that you referenced does not support this, it can marshal only an XML-tree into a response. So you'll need some library that can do XML serialization. One option would be to use [jackson-dataformat-xml](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml) with [jackson-module-scala](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala). It also means you'll have to write your own custom `Marshaller`. Luckily it is not that hard.

So here goes some simple code that might work for you:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.marshalling.{ToResponseMarshallable, Marshaller}

// json marshalling
import akka.http.scaladsl.marshallers.sprayjson.SprayJsonSupport
import spray.json._
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._
implicit val departmentFormat = DefaultJsonProtocol.jsonFormat1(department)
val departmentJsonMarshaller = SprayJsonSupport.sprayJsonMarshaller[department]

// xml marshalling, need to write a custom Marshaller
// there are several MediaTypes for XML such as `application/xml` and `text/xml`, you'll have to choose the one you need.
val departmentXmlMarshaller = Marshaller.StringMarshaller.wrap(MediaTypes.`application/xml`)((d: department) => {
  import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper
  import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
  val mapper = new XmlMapper()
  mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
  mapper.writeValueAsString(d)
})


private val route =
  (pathPrefix("employee") & get) {
    path(Segment) { id =>
      parameters('department ? "") { (flag) =>
        extractUri { uri => {
          flag match {
            case "hr" => {
              // explicitly use the XML marshaller 
              complete(ToResponseMarshallable(department(name = flag))(departmentXmlMarshaller))
            }
            case "tech" => {
              // explicitly use the JSON marshaller 
              complete(ToResponseMarshallable(department(name = flag))(departmentJsonMarshaller))
            }
          }
        }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Note that for Jackson XML serializer to work correctly the `department` class should be a top level class or you'll get a cryptic error about bad root name.

Answer (score 1):

Akka Http already has built in content type negotiation. Ideally you should just use that by having a marshaller that knows how to turn your department into either xml or json and having the client set the `Accept` header.

However it sounds like maybe you can't get your client to do that, so here's what you can do, assuming you have already made a `ToEntityMarshaller[department]` for both xml and json using `ScalaXmlSupport` and `SprayJsonSupport`.

```
val toXmlEntityMarshaller: ToEntityMarshaller[department] = ???
val toJsonEntityMarshaller: ToEntityMarshaller[department] = ???
implicit val departmentMarshaller = Marshaller.oneOf(toJsonEntityMarshaller, toXmlEntityMarshaller)

def route =
  parameters("department") { departmentName =>
    // capture the Accept header in case the client did request one
    optionalHeaderValueByType[Accept] { maybeAcceptHeader => 
      mapRequest ( _
        .removeHeader(Accept.name)
        // set the Accept header based on the department
        .addHeader(maybeAcceptHeader.getOrElse(
          Accept(departmentName match {
            case "hr" ⇒ MediaTypes.`application/xml`
            case "tech" ⇒ MediaTypes.`application/json`
          })
        ))
      ) (
        // none of our logic code is concerned with the response type
        complete(department(departmentName))
        )
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach. And it seems that if the client not just misses the Accept header but sends a wrong one (for example accepting `text/html`), you will have to remove `maybeAcceptHeader.getOrElse` or you need a deeper modification of the contents of the header by adding  `application/xml` or `application/json` to the end of the list with low priority but probably above the `*/*`.

Comment: It's true that this would 406 if the client sent something like a `text/html` Accept header. However I think if a client is explicitly telling you it only knows how to deal with HTML, then sending it back some JSON doesn't make much sense.